# How to use modified node module using github branch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, npm, browserify, browserify-rails

I'm using the [rc-slider](https://github.com/react-component/slider) component in my application and had to 
add one feature to meet my needs.

I forked the main repository and pushed my changes to [this branch](https://github.com/Rodrigora/slider/tree/add-label).

In the application, I changed the `package.json` as below and ran the npm install again:

```
"rc-slider": "Rodrigora/slider#add-label"
```

Nothing changed. Seems that npm doesn't update the dependencies.

So, I removed the `node_modules` and rails cache folder and ran the install command again:

```
rm -rf node_modules/
rake tmp:cache:clear
npm install
```

Now, I have this error:

```
events.js:142
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Cannot find module 'rc-slider' from '/Users/rodrigora/project/app/assets/javascripts'
```

NPM can't find the `rc-slider` when I using the modified branch.

- NPM does not update the dependencies only changing the `package.json` file?
- Should I run some build command to install my branch code?

Comment: Can you post your package.json and `npm -v`? I just tried the suggestion of @Chris911 and the package was successfully installed.

Comment: The error that Rodrigo mentioned will occur during run time and not during ```npm install``` command. The error occurred at  ```require('rc-slider')```. The problem was with the package.json. As this project is a ```reactjs``` project, it must be compiled when installed from github.

Answer (score 4):

In  [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies):

```
"dependencies": {
  "rc-slider": "git://github.com/Rodrigora/slider.git#add-label"
}
```

Also you can use

`npm install git://github.com/Rodrigora/slider.git#add-label --save`

The above command will add that dependency in your `package.json`.

**Edit:**

I miss understood your question. I tried the below fix in the repo that you mentioned and it worked. (you should also have the dependency setup like above)

It is a react project. It is compiled and published to NPM.

So, if you want to install it directly from your github fork, you should make some changes to `package.json`

Before making changes in `package.json` install rc-tools globaly:

`sudo npm install rc-tools -g`

Change the [files](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files) that should be included:

```
"files": [
    "index.js",
    "assets",
    "src"
]
```

and add `postinstall` script in [scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#scripts):

`"postinstall": "rc-tools run compile"`

Then try installing from github after making these changes in that branch.

Answer (score 2):

You can use git repositories as NPM packages:

`"rc-slider": "git://github.com/Rodrigora/slider#add-label"`

Comment: I tried it. But it raises the error `Cannot find module 'rc-slider'`